# alternate word for "coupling"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, context

I'm writing a scientific article.

In my study, the amount of food we eat affects the bodyweight for example. We call it "coupling of food and bodyweight" because bodyweight depends mainly on food and there exists a relation between the amount of food and body weight.

I would like to know if there is an alternate word to **coupling** which can be used in this context.

Comment: Please supply a sentence where you would normally use "coupling". This will help answerers focus on the best solution.

Comment: How about *correlation* or *correspondence*?

Comment: In some contexts "pairing" might be a good term.

Answer (score 2):

"Linking" should work in this context.

> a connection between two people, things, or ideas:

[_Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/link)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Cascabel. I was distracted by the message I got initially saying that my answer was too short (never got one of those before) and was so busy adding words to meet the character minimum that I forgot about a citation. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head: Dependant, co-dependent, interdependent, interdependency, causally related, causal relationship, tied together, bound together, complex.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**joining**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/joining):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : the act or an instance of joining one thing to another : JUNCTURE
>   **2 a** : the place or manner of being joined together
>   **2 b** : something that joins two things together

The *thing* being joined doesn't have to be physical—it can also be conceptual.

As one part of a couple saying something like:

> I *joined* my heart to hers.

Or, in short:

> a *joining* of food and body weight [in a body's overall metabolic processes]

---

Also note the word *joining* can result in the use of the word *joint*:

> A *joining* of individual assets resulted in *joint* ownership.